# Changing customs from a Holy place to a non-Holy place

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, eretz-yisrael, kedusha-holiness

The *mishnah* in Pesachim (4:1) says:

> הַהוֹלֵךְ מִמְּקוֹם שֶׁעוֹשִׂין לִמְקוֹם שֶׁאֵין עוֹשִׂין, אוֹ מִמְּקוֹם שֶׁאֵין עוֹשִׂין לִמְקוֹם שֶׁעוֹשִׂין, נוֹתְנִין עָלָיו חֻמְרֵי מָקוֹם שֶׁיָּצָא מִשָּׁם וְחֻמְרֵי מָקוֹם שֶׁהָלַךְ לְשָׁם. וְאַל יְשַׁנֶּה אָדָם, מִפְּנֵי הַמַּחֲלֹקֶת:
>
> One who goes from a place where they do [work], to a place where they do not do [work], or from a place where they do not do [work] to a place where they do [work], we place upon him the stringencies of the place he came from, [or] the stringencies of the place that he went to. And a man should not deviate [from the established customs of a place], on account of [the] disagreement [to which such conduct may lead].

We see from here that a person should go with the common custom of the place they've traveled to, so long as it doesn't lead to a leniency.

Unfortunately I don't have much to go with. Someone told me that there is an idea somewhere, he believes in the *gemarra*, that this doesn't apply if going from a Holy place/מקום קדוש to a non Holy place/מקום שאינו קדוש. I guess an example would be from Eretz Yisroel to Chutz LaAretz. This doesn't seem correct to me, but he was quoting someone reputable, so I assume someone says it...somewhere. Even if it's not *halacha lema'aseh*...:-) Where can I find such an idea?

Comment: This doesn't seem possible since Israelis can't do work in the diaspora on the second day of Yom Tov

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are looking for [this Gemara in Chulin 18b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.18b?lang=bi).

Here is the key quote from Sefaria.org (with their elaboration) (but the surrounding Gemara is relevant as well):

> The Gemara asks: And does Rabbi Zeira not accept the principle that
>   when a person travels from place to place, the Sages impose upon him
>   the stringencies of the place from which he emerged and the
>   stringencies of the place to which he went?
>
> Abaye said: That statement applies when one travels from one place in
>   Babylonia to another place in Babylonia, or from one place in Eretz
>   Yisrael to another place in Eretz Yisrael, or alternatively, when one
>   descends from Eretz Yisrael to Babylonia. But when one ascends from
>   Babylonia to Eretz Yisrael, this principle does not apply. Since we,
>   the residents of Babylonia, are subordinate to them in terms of
>   halakha, we act in accordance with their custom.
>
> Rav Ashi said: Even if you say that when one travels from Babylonia to
>   Eretz Yisrael, he is required to act stringently in accordance with
>   the custom of the place from which he emerged, that statement applies
>   only in a case where his intent is to return. Rabbi Zeira was not one
>   whose intent was to return. Therefore, he was not obligated to observe
>   the Babylonian stringencies.

Comment: Possibly. Although it was specifically about kedushah vs non kedushah